# How to define Object Property as Function = Correct Syntax?

Tags: typescript, function, types

Can someone please point me to the exact Location of the spec to understand the syntax of line `testMessage: (): string => {`. Shouldn't the syntax be something like `testMessage: () => string;`?  Why are they different?

```
export default {
  Query: {
    testMessage: (): string => {
      return 'Hello World!';
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html

Comment: The first typed example on that page illustrates the use of an inline return type, please clarify what you do not understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit confusing because your `:` has two different functions in the same line: the first is dictionary assignment from JavaScript, and the second is for type information from TypeScript.

```js
let someMessageWithoutReturnType = () => { return 'Hello World!'; }
//                                 ^-- lambda function -----------^

let someMessage =                  (): string => { return 'Hello World!'; }
//                                   ^-type-^
//                                 ^-- lambda function -------------------^
```

In each of the above, the *variable* does not have type information. Instead, the lambda function has optional type information—an explicit return type—as in [standard function syntax in this example in the Functions page of the handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#typing-the-function):

> ```
> function add(x: number, y: number): number {
>    return x + y;
> }
>
> let myAdd = function(x: number, y: number): number { return x + y; };
> ```

This behavior is still the same if you assign inside a dictionary, but the first `:` takes the place of the `=` in assignment while the second `:` supplies the return type information to the function expression. It's unambiguous here because you can't explicitly type the key `someMessage` in your dictionary using a colon; you'd need an explicit cast.

```
let someMessageDict = {
  someMessage: (): string => { return 'Hello World!'; }
//             ^-- lambda function -------------------^
};
```

---

In contrast, the syntax you mentioned is for *typing the variable*, as in the section ["Writing the function type"](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#writing-the-function-type). Note that this time, the variable is explicitly typed, but is not set to any value; there is no implementation for it.

```js
let testMessage: () => string;

class SomeClass {
  testMessage:  () => string;  // defines an unset field
  testMessage2: () => string = SOME_FUNCTION_DECLARED_ELSEWHERE;
  testMessage3: () => string = (): string => { /* ... */ };
}
```

The class definition illustrates where this might be confusing: the `:` refers to type information and `=` would set an initial value. That said, the same logic applies: use `=>` for describing the return type in a type expression, and `:` for annotating an inline function definition (which may use `=>` syntax itself) with a return type.